# Open new window with dynamic javascript content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

Is it possible to open new window with javascript open() function for example, but the window should be empty, so no HTML file and paste content to that, where will be javascript?

I knoww how to open new window, how to paste content there, how to paste styles there (it works) but I paste there  and javascript not working in this opened window.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
function for opening window:

```
function openNewWindow( url ) {
    var OpenWindow = window.open('','_blank','width=1024,height=768,resizable=1');
    var content = document.getElementById('forSBWindow');

    OpenWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>New window</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+url+'style.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+url+'ref/ref.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="'+url+'main.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="'+url+'ref/ref.js"></script></head><body>');
    OpenWindow.document.write( content.outerHTML );
    OpenWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
}
```

And in this new opened window I need for example click on something and call some javascript function from ref.js but it doesn't work

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "paste content"?

Comment: please, see my function in question

Answer (score 0):

I am run through same kind of problem some months before. Following code worked for me: This should help you too.

```
var OpenWindow = window.open('','New Window','width=1024,height=768,resizable=1');
var content = document.getElementById('forSBWindow');

OpenWindow.document.writeln('<html><head><title>New window</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+url+'style.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+url+'ref/ref.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="'+url+'main.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="'+url+'ref/ref.js"></script></head><body>');
    OpenWindow.document.writeln( content.outerHTML );
    OpenWindow.document.writeln('</body></html>');
    OpenWindow.document.close()
$('OpenWindow.document').ready(function(e) {
                        setTimeout(onloadFunction,500);
                    });

function onloadFunction(){ /*code here*/ }
```